# Playing Audio with playback slider in tableView Cell

Tags: ios, swift

How can i play audio with playback slider with play and pause function inside of a tableView cell?
kinda having so much hard time to do it. Can anyone help me in this problem?

[like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXNW2.png)

so i've come up with a solution with the help of @JacobCavin
and come up with this code but still getting nil error report. dont know why.

```
var playerItem:AVPlayerItem?
var player:AVPlayer?
var slider: UISlider?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   startPlayer()
}

func startPlayer() {

    let url = URL(string: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/kargopolov/kukushka.mp3")
    let playerItem:AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

    slider!.minimumValue = 0


    let duration : CMTime = playerItem.asset.duration
    let seconds : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)

    slider!.maximumValue = Float(seconds)
    slider!.isContinuous = false

    slider?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cChatViewController.sliderChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)

    player!.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 1), queue: DispatchQueue.main) { (CMTime) -> Void in
        if self.player!.currentItem?.status == .readyToPlay {
            let time : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player!.currentTime());
            self.slider!.value = Float ( time );
        }

    }

}

//MARK: Private Functions

// Create function for your button
@objc func playPauseTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    if player?.rate == 0
    {
        player!.play()
        //playButton!.setImage(UIImage(named: "player_control_pause_50px.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        //            playButton!.setTitle("Pause", for: UIControlState.normal)
    } else {
        player!.pause()
        //playButton!.setImage(UIImage(named: "player_control_play_50px.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        //            playButton!.setTitle("Play", for: UIControlState.normal)
    }
}


func sliderChanged(sender: UISlider) {

    let seconds : Int64 = Int64(sender.value)
    let targetTime:CMTime = CMTimeMake(seconds, 1)

    player!.seek(to: targetTime)

    if player!.rate == 0
    {
        player?.play()
    }
}


}

extension PopOverViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! MessagesTableViewCell

        cell.outgoingPlayPauseButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playPauseTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.outgoingAudioSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)

        return cell
    }


}

extension PopOverViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

}
```

Comment: Can you give us some more information? What's your code now?

Comment: actually sir i dont know where to start.. :D

Comment: Are you familiar with creating a custom UITableViewCell class?

Comment: yes sir.. and i am currently working with adding audio with playback slider with it.. but dont know how to start..

Comment: so i found a library or a pod.. link in cocoapods . but still dont know how to use it :) shttps://cocoapods.org/pods/JBAudioPlayerView .. beginners problem :(

Comment: so i've come up with a solution with the help of @JacobCavin

and i come up with this code using AVplayer but still getting a nil error report.. dont know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found out the solution for my question and here it is :) thank you so much for the help gals.

here is the full code of my problem

for the view controller..

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class PopOverViewController: UIViewController {

    var playerItem:AVPlayerItem?
    var player:AVPlayer?
    var slider: UISlider?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       startPlayer()
    }

    func startPlayer() {

        let url = URL(string: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/kargopolov/kukushka.mp3")
        let playerItem:AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)



    }

    //MARK: Private Functions

    // Create function for your button
    @objc func playPauseTapped(sender: UIButton) {

        if player?.rate == 0
        {
            player!.play()
            //playButton!.setImage(UIImage(named: "player_control_pause_50px.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            //            playButton!.setTitle("Pause", for: UIControlState.normal)
        } else {
            player!.pause()
            //playButton!.setImage(UIImage(named: "player_control_play_50px.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            //            playButton!.setTitle("Play", for: UIControlState.normal)
        }
    }


    func sliderChanged(sender: UISlider) {

        let seconds : Int64 = Int64(sender.value)
        let targetTime:CMTime = CMTimeMake(seconds, 1)

        player!.seek(to: targetTime)

        player!.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 1), queue: DispatchQueue.main) { (CMTime) -> Void in
            if self.player!.currentItem?.status == .readyToPlay {
                let time : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player!.currentTime());
                sender.value = Float ( time );
            }
        }
        if player?.rate == 0 {
            player?.play()
        }
    }


}
extension PopOverViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! MessagesTableViewCell

        let url = URL(string: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/kargopolov/kukushka.mp3")
        let playerItem:AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

        cell.outgoingAudioSlider.minimumValue = 0
        cell.ingoingAudioSlider.minimumValue = 0

        let duration : CMTime = playerItem.asset.duration
        let seconds : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)


        cell.outgoingAudioSlider.maximumValue = Float(seconds)
        cell.outgoingAudioSlider.isContinuous = false


        cell.outgoingAudioSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cChatViewController.sliderChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)


        cell.outgoingPlayPauseButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playPauseTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)


        cell.outgoingPlayPauseButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playPauseTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.outgoingAudioSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)

        return cell
    }


}

extension PopOverViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

}
```

and for the Table View Cell:

```
import UIKit

class MessagesTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var outgoingAudioContainer: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var outgoingPlayPauseButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var outgoingAudioSlider: UISlider!


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need a `UIViewController` with an `UITableView`. You will also need to create a custom `UITableViewCell` and set up your `UIButton` and `UISlider`. You can find a tutorial for all of that, [here](https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/custom-cells). Once done with that, create variables for those `UIButton` and `UISlider` items in your custom `UITableViewCell`...

```
class PlayerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

      @IBOutlet weak var playPauseButton: UIButton!
      @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!

}
```

Now, in your `UIViewController`, you need to conform to the correct protocol and return your custom `UITableViewCell` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! PlayerTableViewCell

    return cell
}
```

Now we will set up the audio player. Check out the code below that will go in your `UIViewController`...

```
    import UIKit
    // You need to import AVFoundation
    import AVFoundation

    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

        // Create a variable for your audio player
        var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            do {
                // Create the path of the audio file you have in your project. For example: songname.mp3
                if let fileURL = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "songname", ofType: "mp3") {
                    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: fileURL))
                    // Now to play the song
                    audioPlayer?.play()
                } else {
                    print("No file with that name exists")
                }
            } catch let error {
                print("Plaing the file failed with an error \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }


        }

        // Create function for your button
        @objc func playPauseTapped(sender: UIButton) {
            if (audioPlayer?.isPlaying)! {
                // Since the audioPlayer is playing, we want to pause the music
                audioPlayer?.pause()
                // We will change the button's (sender's) image to reflect the change
                sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "play"), for: .normal)
            } else {
                // Since the audioPlayer is NOT playing, we want to play the music
                audioPlayer?.play()
                // We will change the button's (sender's) image to reflect the change
                sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause"), for: .normal)
            }
        }

// Change the audioPlayer's current time when the slider is changed
    @objc func sliderChanged(sender: UISlider) {
        audioPlayer?.currentTime = TimeInterval(sender.value)
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! YourCustomCellClass

        // Set up your Play/Pause button's action
        cell.playPauseButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playPauseTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        // Set up the slider
        cell.slider.maximumValue = Float((audioPlayer?.duration)!)
        cell.slider.value = Float((audioPlayer?.currentTime)!)
        cell.slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
        return cell
    }
}
```

And there you go! Now you can control the audio from an `UITableViewCell`. If you want the `UISlider` to reflect the current time of the song, set up a `Timer` to go off every second and update the slider's value...

```
slider.value = Float((audioPlayer?.currentTime)!)
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: thank you so much sir. now i have an idea.. thank u so much for the help very well appreciated.. love lots from phil.

Comment: @JoreDawal No problem! If my answer worked for you, you can accept it by pressing the check right underneath the rate buttons at the top. This lets other people with this same problem know that the answer worked and gives me credit for my answer. Anyways, I'm glad I could help! Happy coding!